# Error connecting oracle database that uses PKI

Tags: sql, oracle, security, pki

I am trying to setup PKI in oracle Database.
I am able to do tnsping and also see the listener status is OK.
I did the certificate exchange with sha 256 and self signed certificates.

When I try to connect from client, I get following error (Is there any way to find the root cause of this error):

```
sqlplus /@dbserver-check

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Jul 20 10:56:19 2022
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

Here is the tnsnames.ora file:

```
DBSERVER =
 (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = host)(PORT = port))
   (CONNECT_DATA=
     (SERVER = DEDICATED)
     (SERVICE_NAME=service-name)
   )
  )
DBSERVER-CHECK =
 (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = host)(PORT = port))
   (CONNECT_DATA=
     (SERVER = DEDICATED)
     (SERVICE_NAME=service-name)
   )
   (SECURITY=(SSL_SERVER_CERT_DN="CN=DBSERVER"))
  )
```

Comment: Is the DB started? Not just the listener

Comment: Yes the status is open

Comment: can you modify the question to show us the definition of dbserver-check in tnsnames.ora?

Comment: Done, updated the question with tnsnames.ora file contents, also please note that tnsping dbserver-check works fine.

Comment: @AmitMahajan tnsping only checks listener availability, it doesn't validate service_name or database availability.

Comment: And what does "lsnrctl stat" give you? Basically the error is saying that the DB is not up. So either the listener is trying to connect to a different DB than the one you're trying to access, or there's some mismatch in the config

Comment: I was able to solve the issue, the problem was I was trying to create a new SID and service entry dedicated for SSL use which was not working. When i use existing service name I was able to connect using SSS(2484)